# Mindmapping example with KineticJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kineticjs, mindmapping

I want to create a mapper (like mindmapping) with KineticJS and JQuery. But I didn't find how to begin with KineticJS. Actually, I only need some example to draw a box (some shape) in the middle of the page with just one arrow.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So your question is how to make a shape and an arrow on a page?

Comment: What is a mapper/ what do you mean by mind-mapping (there is quite a variety)?

Comment: At this moment, I need to make only a shape and one arrow

Answer (score 1):

You can do arrows with paths :
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-path-tutorial/

You can also do that with polygons :
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-polygon-tutorial/

And to draw a box, you simply have to draw a rect :
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-rect-tutorial/

The KineticJS documentation and tutorials are very simple to use.

Hope it will help.

Comment: You can also see that an arrow plugin will be added to Kinetic in the next release. https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/wiki/Release-Schedule